# How can I do a Query/Retrieve in JAVA?

Tags: java, dicom, dcm4che

I need to acces to the `DicomObjects` that are stored in a `DCM4CHEE PACS` using `JAVA` `(NetBeans)`.

So far, I think that I have to use the class `DCMqr` from `DCM4CHE` library, but I can't find any example and I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Worked on the DICOM before, please send me your email id so that we can have a private chat rather it takes a bit of time to check as I don't have access to PACS.

Comment: Hi! I will appreciate it! My email is edurod27@gmail.com
I don't know if StackOverflow has a "inner-chat". thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [dcm4che toolkit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dcm4che/files/dcm4che2/2.0.26/) usage doc for dcmqr is available [here](http://www.dcm4che.org/confluence/display/d2/dcmqr)

The toolkit has a [dcmqr class](/dcm4che-2.0.26/dcm4che-tool/dcm4che-tool-dcmqr/src/main/java/org/dcm4che2/tool/dcmqr/DcmQR.java) which provides all of the functionality to do a `C-FIND` or `C-MOVE` from a DCM4CHEE PACS (or any other DICOM compliant PACS).

Simply pass the AE Title, host and port and possibly other options to the `DcmQR` main method.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to include the dcm4che jar-files in your source-path (eg.g commons.cli jar, core jar, net-jar and others
   Y
2. You have to call the dcm4che Q/R like
   dcmqr.main(argst) where argst is as String Array with your parameter like `argst[0]="Port"
   argst[1]="server"`